How do I await an async task within `ProcessDialogKey`
I'm dragging an old Windows Forms application to the 2020's, refactoring it as I go. There is a form where the existing code reacts to a keyboard shortcut and then calls an IO-bound method. I have "asyncified" that IO-bound method, but now I'm not sure what the best way to await that method is.
Here's the code, paraphrased:
 protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
 {
     var result = base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
     if (!result)
     {
         if (keyData == (Keys.G | Keys.Control))
         {
             // Ctrl-G pressed, perform the I/O
             DisableUiControls();
             IoBoundMethod();                // <-- this blocks
             // await IoBoundMethodAsync();  // <-- I want something like this.
             EnableUicontrols();
             result = true;
         }
     }
}

ProcessDialogKey is not a Windows forms event handler but a "hook" provided by the framework. Its signature is not a Task so I cannot make the method async. What is a good approach here?
I have a vague notion that I could "post" an awaitable delegate, which the message pump would dispatch to later, and then perform the await there, I'm just not sure how to put all the pieces together.

Why is ProcessDialogKey used in the first place? That's the real problem. I don't remember using that method in .... 20 years. And what does IoBoundMethod do? Both matter. You don't need ProcessDialogKey to handle key presses, the ``KeyDown` event is enough and can check for Ctlr+G. You can use an async event handler, disable the UI before callingt he async method and then re-enabling it

If the framework didn't intend ProcessDialogKey to be async then it probably shouldn't be. If you however really need to do async work, then you'll have to do the ol' async void "trick". Basically, async tasks in C# are eager, meaning they are executed even if you don't await them, meaning you can do something like this:
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    DoIoBoundWorkAsync();
}

async void DoIoBoundWorkAsync()
{
    await IoBoundMethodAsync();
}

This will not block the UI and run the IO work asynchronously on a background thread.
There's still one problem though, in your example you're updating the UI, and you can only update the UI from the UI thread, so you'll have to use the Invoke method on the UI component, something like this
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    var result = base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    if (!result)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.G | Keys.Control))
        {
            // Ctrl-G pressed, perform the I/O
            DisableUiControls();
            DoIoBoundWorkAsync();
            result = true;
        }
    }

    // The rest of your ProcessDialogKey method
}

async void DoIoBoundWorkAsync()
{
    await IoBoundMethodAsync();
    Invoke(() => EnableUicontrols());
}

P.S. don't forget error handling, as unawaited tasks are problematic for exception handling. It is however also quite easy, you can simply wrap the await IoBoundMethodAsync(); in a try-catch and propagate that to the UI thread with Invoke if you want.

Re: error handling - wrapping the body of DoIoBoundWorkAsync inside of a try-catch and using Invoke() to execute the exception handler on the UI thread seems to be working fine. I like this answer the best so far.

maybe you can edit your answer to show the error handler logic (apologies for the formatting):
private async void DoIoBoundWorkAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await IoBoundMethodAsync();
        Invoke(() => EnableUiControls());
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Invoke(() => DisplayError(ex));
    }
}


Are you sure that the code in DoIoBoundWorkAsync() is executed in a ThreadPool Thread? I guess it's not (with async void here, .ConfigureAwait(false) is also irrelevant) -- result is not returned

async void methods capture the SynchronizationContext when they start executing. Using the Invoke is redundant.
